# Помогите исправить ошибки в коде, нужно выводить текст "Kulakivskyi V.Y." желтого цвета

Tags: c++, консоль

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

SetConsoleTextAttribute(handle, FOREGROUND_YELLOW);
system("color 6" );
cout << "Kulakivskyi V.Y.";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
                        FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
cout << "Kulakivskyi V.Y.";
```

И никаких `color 6`!

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "\033[1;33m";
    std::cout << "Желтый текст" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\033[0m";

    std::cout << "\033[1;31m";
    std::cout << "Красный текст" << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "\033[0m";
}
```

Вот табличка цветов

```
black        30
red          31
green        32
yellow       33
blue         34
magenta      35
cyan         36
white        37
```